# Simulador de digitação

Tags: vb.net

Queria saber como posso fazer com que o programa digite sozinho, é como enviar mensagem com sendkeys mas vai letra por letra como se fosse um humano digitando.

Eu tinha feito da maneira comum para enviar uma mensagem, mas preciso q seja enviada devagar e não consegui:

```
    Dim F1 As Boolean
        F1 = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F1)
Select Case F1
            Case F1
                If F1 And MetroComboBox1.Text = "F1" = True Then
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(MetroTextBox1.Text)
                    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
                    SendKeys.Send("^v{ENTER}")
                ElseIf F1 And MetroComboBox2.Text = "F1" = True Then
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(MetroTextBox2.Text)
                    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
                    SendKeys.Send("^v{ENTER}")
                ElseIf F1 And MetroComboBox3.Text = "F1" = True Then
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(MetroTextBox3.Text)
                    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
                    SendKeys.Send("^v{ENTER}")
                ElseIf F1 And MetroComboBox4.Text = "F1" = True Then
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(MetroTextBox4.Text)
                    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
                    SendKeys.Send("^v{ENTER}")
                End If
        End Select
```

Eu queria sabe como faço para que as mensagens que envio do textbox1 sejam enviadas devagar, letra por letra

tentei também implantar este código no meu projeto mas não tive sucesso, ele basicamente faz o efeito que quero mas em velocidade menor e em uma label do programa:

```
Public Class Form2
    Dim i As Integer = -1
    Dim mensagem As String
    Private Sub ExibirMensagem(ByVal msg As String)
        Timer1.Stop()
        i = -1
        Label1.Text = Nothing
        mensagem = msg
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim tamanho As Integer = mensagem.Length
        i = i + 1
        If i = tamanho Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            i = -1
        Else
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text & mensagem.Chars(i)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ExibirMensagem(TextBox1.Text)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Será que resolveria com `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)` ?

Comment: eu ja tinha testado isso mas ele só faz com que leve tempo para o comando ser executado, mas quando o comando é exectado a frase é mandada como um ctrl+V. Existe algum comando alternativo do sendkeys?